# Returning from rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Here's a beginner rails question...

After I do:

```
format.xml { head: ok}
```

How do I return from the controller endpoint without showing the view?  If I drop off the end of the function at this point, I get what I expect, but if I call 'return', I end up in the view (or in my case in a missing view template).  I can code up lots of if/else etc., but it would be nice to early out from the function without ending up in a view template.

I've searched around and can't figure out what the obvious answer is to this; it must be straightforward...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use "`render :nothing => true, :status => :ok`" to return without rendering anything, once you have send a render :nothing => true you need to return from the controller, something like this might work. You can swap the `head()` method call for a `render => :nothing` followed by a `return`, the `head()` method is documented here:

- [api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000635](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000635)

Here's the code that should do it for you...

- [gist.github.com/126367](http://gist.github.com/126367)

Ping me if that doesn't properly answer your question, documentation for the render call with some helpful user comments can be found here:

- [apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render)

(sorry I couldn't hyperlink the links for you, as a new user stackoverflow won't allow me to post more than one!)

Answer (score 4):

Use

`render :nothing => true, :status => :ok`

in your action method

Answer (score 2):

I guess you must be asking for :

```
render :nothing => true
```