# Returning from rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As a follow up for this question [Returning from rails controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968799/returning-from-rails-controller) how can I return false. I need to call the controller function to check for an ID.

If the ID exists I need to return `true`. Otherwise, I need to return `false`.

To return `true`, I am using : `{render :nothing => true, :status => :ok}`

I am using below code. Is there a better way of solving this problem.

```
if true
  render :text => "true"
else
  render :text => "false"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand if you need to write true/false as a string or if your method need to return a true/false value.

In the former case, assuming you have a conditions that evaluates true/false, you can do

```
def action
  render :text => condition
end
```